# PHP find why variable is changing

Tags: php

I'm trying to remove $ signs and replace with a const that changes based on region. My issue is that on one part of the site, when an item is customized, the currency returns back to $.

I simply cannot find it inside the code. Is there a way I can see a response from my localhost to see what is pushing this change in the code?

Comment: If you use an IDE for development, such as Netbeans you can setup a debugger to allow you to step through PHP code line by line which is very useful at situations like this.

Comment: Debugging tools like xdebug should allow you to set watch conditions to see when a variable changes value

Comment: Thank You! Just started using PHP Storm so not really familiar with all the features. Will look into debug.

Comment: Removed excess, Better title.